# Cannot install any drive in Windows 7 64 bits, file version not compatible

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers

I have a Windows 7 SP1 installed and I am trying to install drivers from Gigabyte and Nvidia.

I made sure I have a W7 64 bits, went to properties and checked system settings and it says its 64 bits.

Then I donwloaded the correct drivers from other PC (a linux), put them in a USB drive and tried to run them on the W7.

For example this one from Nvidia:

- Versione:    388.59  WHQL
- Fecha de publicación:    2017.12.7
- Sistema operativo:   Windows 7 64-bit, Windows 8.1 64-bit, Windows 8 64-bit
- Idioma:  Español (España)
- Tamaño:  398.64 MB

And also the correct 64 bits driver from Gigabyte motherboard, which are like different drivers for LAN, Sound, Chipset etc

Then, all of them, when I try to run them on W7 it appears a message like this:

> "This verison of this file is not compatible with the version of
>   Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to
>   see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) verion of the
>   program.

This is the obvious message when you try to install a 64 bits driver on a 32 bits OS but its not the case, I tried to run the drivers in compatible mode or tried also the automatic compatibility fix which has W7 but didnt work, is not possible anymore to install those drivers?

Comment: "it says its 64 bits." - we'll need an exact message, please [edit] your question and include it.

Comment: What do you mean with exact message? a screenshoot? I meant I went to My PC -> properties, System Type: Operating System 64 bits

Comment: Something like this https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/xmtb_4-650x480.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+ws+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.BjOLBmD7Kt.png

Comment: Just include the exact text that you see in Properties window, like you did with the error message. *"System type: ..."*. Even if it's in Spanish.

Comment: Why did you download the drivers on another PC? And are you sure you downloaded x86_64 drivers, and not drivers based on that PC's OS?